Meaning of おしで in this sentence

....あそこの警備は
見かけだおしで盗みやすかったぜ

What does おしで mean here?

It should be broken down into 見かけ, 倒し and で.

It is みかけだおし

［名・形動］外見はすぐれているが、実質は劣っていること。また、そのさま。「—の臆病者」

It means something does not have the quality as expected from the outside appearance. In the particular sentence, the security looks tight, but it really isn't.
